# How can I check who has write access to a public organization's repository on Github?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

I am trying to find out users who have write access to a repository or a particular directory in the repo (especially for huge code bases). How do I find that out from Github's website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tab "people" of an organization ([such as dolores](https://github.com/orgs/dolores/people)) will list the *public* members.

Note that the page "[Permission levels for an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization/)" shows that only members and owners can see all members of an organization.
A non-member would see only the public members.

You can check out the [GitHub API Organization member](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/) for more details.

Comment: It doesn't show who has write access though - it only shows the member of the organization, some of which don't have write access.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. True. I suppose you would have to review each user's permission with https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#review-a-users-permission-level